# Qt/C++: Getting the data at a certain cell in a QTableView

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview

I'm trying to get the text at a certain cell in a `QTableView`. For example:

```
QString codestring = "*" + ui->tblInventory->indexAt(QPoint(0,2)).data().toString() + "*";
```

This should get the text at the cell in column 0 row 2 in my `QTableView`. The problem is, that's not what it's doing!. Regardless of the arguments I pass into the `QPoint()` in the `indexAt()`, I get the text at cell 0,0. I have no idea why this is... any help? Thanks!

[edit]
I've also tried this:

```
QString codestring = "*" + ui->tblInventory->model()->data(ui->tblInventory->indexAt(QPoint(0,2))).toString() + "*";
```

[Edit 2]
Trying to find out what's going on, I put in this line of code:

```
qDebug()<< ui->tblInventory->indexAt(QPoint(2,2)).row() << " and " <<  ui->tblInventory->indexAt(QPoint(2,2)).column();
```

It should get the `QModelIndex` at cell 2,2 and output its row and its column, which of course should be 2 and 2. However, I get 0 and 0! So it seems like this might be a problem with `QTableView::indexAt()`, whether its my usage or some sort of bug. Can anyone shed some light?

Comment: indexAt(QPoint(0,2) would return QModelIndex of a cell at the widget position X=0 Y=2, not Row/Col 0,2

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Resolved with:

```
ui->tblInventory->model()->data(ui->tblInventory->model()->index(0,2)).toString()
```

Not quite sure why the above doesn't work, but this does. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I think it's because QPoint is used to get a value based on certain position of the cursor. I'm using QPoint to get the cell value based on a right click.

Comment: indexAt() returns the index at a certain *pixel position* in the view. (0,2) is just two pixels from the top border, and thus corresponds to index(0,0). Btw, ui->tblInventory->model()->index(0,2).data().toString() also works.

Answer (score 10):

This one work too and it's shorter:

```
QModelIndex index = model->index(row, col, QModelIndex());

ui->tblInventory->model()->data(index).toString();
```

(`model` used top is the QAbstractModel that is bound to this `tblInventory`)

Comment: it is not about shorter or longer. Here you create extra instances that's make his solution better. Good job anyway

Answer (score 0):

Check the `data()` function provided by the model that your QTableView uses, the effect that you describe is probably observed due to a bug in it.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more? I'm using QSqlQueryModel. I've also attempted:     QString codestring = "*" + ui->tblInventory->model()->data(ui->tblInventory->indexAt(QPoint(0,2))).toString() + "*";   but this doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
QModelIndex index = ui->tblInventory->indexAt(p); // p is a QPoint you get from some where, may be you catch right click
QString codestring = "*" + index->data().toString() + "*";
```